# How to avoid empty rows being imported into Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to import a .csv file using pandas into a dataframe. The csv file has the following form;

```
Timestamp,Electricity Price (p/kWh),
2019-07-31 23:30:00+00:00,7.245
2019-08-01 00:00:00+00:00,7.245
2019-08-01 00:30:00+00:00,7.455
2019-08-01 01:00:00+00:00,7.245
2019-08-01 01:30:00+00:00,7.245
```

The code that I am currently trying is;

```
price_data = pd.read_csv(price_path, index_col='Timestamp', infer_datetime_format='True')
price_data.index = pd.to_datetime(price_data.index)
```

However, this is returning a data frame that has an extra empty row

price_data.head()

```
               Electricity Price (p/kWh)    Unnamed: 2
Timestamp       
2019-07-31 23:30:00                7.245    NaN
2019-08-01 00:00:00                7.245    NaN
2019-08-01 00:30:00                7.455    NaN
2019-08-01 01:00:00                7.245    NaN
2019-08-01 01:30:00                7.245    NaN
```

I have searched the .csv for any double commas, which might cause this, but have not found this.

If I remove the comma on the first line ie

```
 Timestamp,Electricity Price (p/kWh)
```

rather than

```
 Timestamp,Electricity Price (p/kWh),
```

I get the following error message;

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 48, saw 3

Comment: Did you look at line 48 of your csv file?

Comment: Hahaha, I did not, really should have

Comment: this is line 47: `2019-08-01 22:00:00+00:00,7.56`
and this is line 48: `2019-08-02T21:30:00Z,8.4,`

Comment: Is it because the format has changed? I get that would mess it up, but why is it 'seeing 3 fields' there isn't another comma?

Comment: Delete the comma on line 48 and header or add an extra column name on the header?

Comment: There should be another comma if the error persists. Anyway, you can always `dropna('all')` on the dataFrame.